# python docstrings - while loop containing try, break and except

Tags: python

How would I write my docstrings for a method that uses try and except in a while loop. the loop breaks if input is correct. Also is this proper/ good practice code or should I define a variable and set it to true,  implement a Raise and and  write an if else statement?

```
def validate_num():

    while True:
        try:
            pick_num = input("enter a number")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid number re-enter.")
```

I was going to write the following doc string:

```
def validate_num():
    ''' Requests user to enter number
    
        except:
           ValueError if a non int is entered.
    '''

    while True:
        try:
            pick_num = input("enter a number")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid number re-enter.")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function doesn't raise `ValueError`, the docstring shouldn't mention it.  The idea of the docstring is that it says what the caller of the function should expect its result to be, and *not* what happens inside the function.

If I were documenting exactly what the function does as you've written it, I would write:

```
def validate_num() -> None:
    """Promps the user to enter a number.  
    Does not validate or return the result."""
    while True:
        try:
            pick_num = input("enter a number")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid number re-enter.")
```

If I were to fix the function to do what I think you meant it to do, and document *that*, it would look like this:

```
def validate_num() -> int:
    """Returns an integer entered by the user, 
    re-prompting on invalid input."""
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("enter a number"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid number re-enter.")
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I always document Returns: none even if the function does not contain a return statement?

Comment: Not if it's obvious from context/naming IMO.  In the first version of the function I thought it was important to note that it returns nothing since it would likely be surprising to a caller of that function that the number the user enters is discarded (given the name `validate_num` which implies validation).  The goal is for the purpose of the function to be quickly and easily understood, which is why you want to omit implementation details -- that information is irrelevant and will therefore only be a hindrance.  The same is true of explaining anything the reader will certainly already know.